# javascript remove html tags without regex

Tags: javascript

I have a function that must remove html tags in a string, here's my code:

```
var text = jsConsole.read("#tb-first");
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === '<') {
    do {
      text.replace(text[i], '');
      i++;
    } while (text[i] !== '>');
    text.replace(text[i], '');
  }
}
jsConsole.writeLine(text);
```

Here's my input: 
`<html><head><title>sample site</title></head><body><div>text<div>more text</div>and more...</div>in body</body></html>`

But I get this output:

```
text
more text
and more...
in body
```

I'm pretty new to javascript, can someone explain why 'samle site' isn't in the output ?

Comment: Use the DOM for this, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because it is not there to begin with. Check `jsConsole.read("#tb-first")` first and see what's in it.

```
console.log(jsConsole.read("#tb-first"));
```